# Why can't I access xml message in Mirth?

Tags: xml, mirth, e4x

I have a channel in Mirth which is receiving an XML message via HTTP, but when I try to access attributes and fields of the message, I cannot.  If I copy and paste a message into "Send Message" it works, but if reprocess it does not work.  In "Raw" it looks fine, but occasionally in "Transformed" it is xml encoded

Example message:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test attr="foo" />
```

Example message as shown in "Transformed":

```xml
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot; ?&gt;
&lt;test attr=&quot;foo&quot; /&gt;
```

Example javascript:

```js
 channelMap.put('rootElementName', msg.localName());    // value is null
 channelMap.put('attrValue', msg['@attr'].toString());  // undefined is not XML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two factors contribute to this sort of failure:

Firstly, E4X does not support the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` declaration [(bug 336551: You may get SyntaxError "xml is a reserved identifier")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X#Known_bugs_and_limitations).  You can fix it by adding a preprocessor to remove the declaration:

```js
return message.replace(/<\?xml[^>]*\?>/, "");
```

To further confuse, the XML Declaration is hidden in the message viewer if you have "Format XML Message" checked.

Secondly, if you are receiving the message from anything .Net, you likely have a byte-order mark at the front of the message.  The first three bytes are likely nonprintable, and may need to be removed for the XML to parse in Mirth.

Again, preprocessor to the rescue ([Example 1](https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/9385-file-reader-with-xml-has-extra-chars-in-prolog?t=9169), [Example 2](https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/17964-utf-8-bom-remove-special-characters-xml-reader#post100915)):

```js
return message.replace(/\uFEFF/g,'');
```

Comment: This is very good information.   I would also recommend placing your XML into a validation tool to make sure that it is properly formatted.  (DO NOT use an online validation tool if your XML contains patient information)

Comment: If you download vanilla Rhino, it will not support the xml declaration (it will throw an error and refuse to parse the xml.) Mirth reimplements a few Rhino classes to add support. The BOM will definitely cause an issue. When using the `new XML()` constructor, which is how the transformer creates `msg`, if the first character encountered is not `<` it treats the entire thing as an xml text node. This is why the `.toXMLString()` value you see in the transformed content has xml encoded the message.

Comment: @agermano, that makes sense. It seems odd that I never would have run into a declaration causing a problem before. Must have just been the BOM, then.